# Data not passing in ajax call in Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

I am sending a file through ajax. Instead of passing the csrf token its not available in the controller
Bellow is code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var csrfName = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>',
    csrfHash = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>';
$(document).on("change","#channel_setup_file",function(e){

    var formData = new FormData($("#process-form")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('parse-setup-file')?>",
        type:   "POST",
        data: {cform : formData,csrfName:csrfHash},
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        error:  function(msg){
        },
        success: function(msg){
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I am getting only the url in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Expecting that you are getting both token and name so in context to that I am writing the code

```
var formData = new FormData($("#process-form")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('parse-setup-file')?>",
        type:   "POST",
        data: {cform : formData,cName:csrfName,cToken:csrfHash},
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        error:  function(msg){
        },
        success: function(msg){
        }
    });
```

Comment: Since the CI will look for the csrf token name in the post request(suppose the name is csrf_tokan). As per you code you have assign token name to cName which means csrf token not found as csrf_token (which contains the token value) not found in the request.
Sine the CI will look for the csrf_token in the request and it will not find it and redirects you to the you are not authorize to perform this action.